# Run sylius project in prod mode

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I am a beginner in sylius. I am trying to run my sylius project in prod mode, because dev mode is very long. I modified the env file:

```
APP_ENV=prod
APP_DEBUG=0
APP_SECRET=EDITMEXYZ
```

Then I launched the following command:

```
symfony serve
```

The project run in prod mode but sometimes i got the following error as shown in the image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzFYc.png)

In the console I got the following error

```
 [Web Server/PHP ] Aug 31 12:39:04 |ERROR| SERVER POST (500) /admin/orders/36/payments/38/complete host="127.0.0.1:8004" scheme="https"
```

Comment: All it says is that this is an error 500 (internal server error). Turn debug on, with `APP_DEBUG=1`, if you don't get more details in the logs. Gonna be hard to help without that additional debug information.

Comment: Always the same description in the log:
[Web Server/PHP ] Sep  1 10:28:10 |ERROR| SERVER POST (500) /admin/orders/40/payments/42/complete host="127.0.0.1:8004" scheme="https"